# On Tumblr, is there a way to specify track titles for the Streampad player?

Tags: javascript, audio, tumblr, streampad

I'm using Streampad on a Tumblr-powered site and am running into an irritating little problem. By default, Streampad takes the captions to audio posts and uses them for the track titles, chopping them off awkwardly mid-sentence when it runs out of space (516px worth).

If you just use the "artist - track title" format for posts, that works just fine. As soon as you decide to start adding any kind of description or commentary, however, Streampad becomes a confusing mess for anyone interested in knowing what they're listening to.

I was wondering if there was any way to specify which text to include in Streampad's audio caption while excluding the rest of the post. Ideally, I'd like to have the player take the track information from Tumblr's {artist} and {TrackName} blocks, but I'd be happy with anything that allows me to add commentary to audio posts without it showing up in the Streampad player. If it's possible to do it cleanly with Javascript, great. I'd settle for a hack, though.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try Tumblr Music Player instead at http://tumblrplayer.com and all your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a post about Streampad here:
http://justcantdescribeu.tumblr.com/post/18873243263

If you scroll to the bottom, you can find a script that instructs Streampad to grab the ID3 artist and ID3 title via Tumblr's API, instead of the usual audio post description.

There's a fallback too, in case there is no ID3 metadata.
I'm a year late, but just wanted to give you and anyone else a heads up in case anyone's still looking for a solution to this. :)

Comment: Please provide a short description of what you posted there, links may be always be broken in the future.